# query between 3 Mysql tables per time range

Tags: mysql

I am working on a small database that records rentals of different properties for different periods of time to different clients. **I leave a summary example of the structures of my tables below**.

```
+--------------+
|   customer   |
|--------------|
| id           |
| name         |
+--------------+

+--------------+
|   property   |
|--------------|
| id           |
| number       |
| address      |
+--------------+

+--------------+
|   rental     |
|--------------|
| id           |
| date_init    |
| date_end     |
| month_payment|
| customer_id  |
| property_id  |
+--------------+
```

What I am trying to find out now through a consultation is the following: in my rental table I keep the client, property and amount that I agree to cancel each month for the rental, so there are clients who rent different properties, during the year. How can I know how much money my clients have generated during a certain period of time, for example if I have the following records:

```
customer
+--------------+
| id |  name   |
|--------------|
| 1  | jhon doe|
| 2  | alex gs |
| 3  | martha  |
+--------------+

property
+------------------------------------+
| id  |   number    | address        |
--------------------------------------
| 1   | 5643        | chicago        |
| 2   | 1023        | toronto        |
| 3   | 3445        | atlanta        |
+------------------------------------+

rental
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | customer_id | property_id | date_init  | date_end   | amount |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1           | 1           | 2019-01-05 | 2019-06-05 |3000    |
| 2  | 2           | 2           | 2019-04-10 | 2019-10-10 |1800    |
| 3  | 1           | 3           | 2019-02-14 | 2019-11-14 |1000    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

then given as a parameter a period of time for example: `2019-01-01` to `2019-12-30` get only the records that match and have the following result:

```
+---------------------+
| customer | total    |
|----------------------
| jhon doe | 24,000   |
| alex gs  | 10,800   | 
+---------------------+
```

In this case, the John Doe client has rented 2 properties the first for 5 months for an amount of 3000 total of 15000 and the other property for 9 months to 1000 total of 9000, so is it possible to make a query with this type of data? I don't have a query as an example yet, since I don't know how to deal with this problem. I am working on it, as soon as I have something I will update my question, thank you!

Comment: What if the property was rented for 5 month 10 days?

Comment: At the moment we are taking that as if it were within the month, for example if it were 2019-01-05 to 2019-06-15, it is still within 5 months so we only take this

Comment: What if portion of the matched record lies outside the dates in where clause? E.g. for 2019-01-01 to 2019-12-30 there is a row with 2018-12-01 ... 2019-02-01.

Comment: then I should only count the months until the deadline (the date up to the parameter), if that's what you mean, I'm sorry if I didn't understand correctly

Answer (score 0):

edited--

You need to use SUM() and a JOIN then specify the fields you want returned.

```
SELECT c.name AS customer, SUM(r.amount) AS total 
FROM rentals r 
    INNER JOIN customer c ON c.id = r.customer_id 
WHERE r.date_end >= $START AND r.date_end <= $END 
GROUP BY r.customer_id
```

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-aggregate-functions/sql-server-sum/

Comment: You need a ```GROUP BY``` if you're going to ```SUM```